# Derivative of a function being equal to 0

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f(x, 0) = 0$ for all $x$ in some domain of definition. Let $g = \partial f/\partial x$. Does it follow that $g(x, y) = 0$ for all $(x, y)$ in our domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for example:
$$f(x,y)=xy$$
$$f(x,0)=0$$
$$g(x,y)=y$$